# java NullPointerException when selecting items in a JList

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what is wrong with my JList. I have a DefaultListModel object containing a custom data type which is populated from a HashMap of those objects. Everything works fine until there are 16 or more objects in the group. Here is what happens:

[image: 01]
[image: 02]
[image: 03]
[image: 04]
[image: 05]

As you can tell, there are suddenly empty spaces in the list, even though the HashMap it is populating from doesn't have any null objects. Also, here is the code used to populate the JList:

```
for(Entry<Integer, TV_Season_v2> e : rc.shows.get(index).seasons.entrySet()){
    seasonslistmodel.addElement(e.getValue());
}
```

and here is the line which gives a null pointer exception:

```
int mapSeasonIndex = seasonsList.getSelectedValue().getSeasonNum();
```

What is going on?

Comment: Where have you initialized `seasonsList` in code?

Comment: way at the beginning of the constructor: seasonslistmodel = new DefaultListModel<TV_Season_v2>();
  seasonsList = new JList<TV_Season_v2>(seasonslistmodel);

Comment: I would guess that at some point the selected value is NULL

Answer (score 0):

If you get NPE in the line given above, I'm sure that `seasonsList.getSelectedValue()` is `null`. From the JList.getSelectedValue() Javadoc:

> Returns {@code null} if there is no selection.

Then there's the empty cells... I really cannot tell without more code being shown, but could it be `e.getValue()` is `null` for some entries?

```
for(Entry<Integer, TV_Season_v2> e : rc.shows.get(index).seasons.entrySet()){
    seasonslistmodel.addElement(e.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but it does that when nothing is selected. The bigger question is, why are there empty lines in the list of seasons?

Comment: Who knows why there are empty lines in the list of seasons. You must have added an Empty string. Only you can add println(...) statement as you add items to the list to confirm.

Comment: I would post the code, but there is well over 1000 lines just in the parts that deal with this one issue. If I add season 15 and there are season's less than 15 that don't exist, it adds them properly, but if I add any season greater than 15, it produces the nullpointerexception and blank entries in the list (I have the same problem with the episodes, which also use HashMap)

Comment: `but there is well over 1000 lines just ` The problem is with your data. Only you have access to the data so unless you can post a proper `SSCCE` that demonstrates how you create the data and load it into a JList, we can't help.

Comment: My apologies. I am still learning about the conventions in programming as well as the subtelties of many of the common languages. What would you suggest I do/where should I look to learn what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure **seasonsList** is properly initialized.

Comment: It is properly initialized. As best as I can tell, it seems to have problems adding items from a HashMap if there are 16 or more items in the hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem for anyone stumbling upon my badly-worded question is to implement ones own loop for populating the list.

Originally, I used a java enhanced for loop like so:

```
for(Entry<Integer, TV_Episode_v2> e : rc.shows.get(showIndex).seasons.get(mapSeasonIndex).episodes.entrySet()){
        episodeslistmodel.add(e.getKey()-1,e.getValue());
}
```

For some reason, this method iterates through null results if episodes.size() is greater than 15, so I implemented my own method of iteration:

```
//Add elements to list model
int i = 0; //variable to show the index
int c = 0; //variable to count the number of episodes
while(c < rc.shows.get(showIndex).seasons.get(seasonIndex+1).episodes.size()){
    if(rc.shows.get(showIndex).seasons.get(seasonIndex+1).episodes.containsKey(i)){ //if the season contains the key i
        episodeslistmodel.add(i-1, rc.shows.get(showIndex).seasons.get(seasonIndex+1).episodes.get(i)); //add to the list
        c++; //increment up to count the number of objects found
    }
    i++;
}
```

This produces no errors and puts all items in the proper place in the JList. I hope this is helpful to anyone reading this post.